# A* search two possibilities

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, a-star

I'm trying to implement the A* search algo in C++. My issue is that my implementation doesn't pick one of the options but explorers both of them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using std::istringstream;
using std::sort;

enum class State {
    kEmpty, kObstacle, kClosed, kStart, kFinish, kPath
};

const int directionDeltas[4][2]{
        {0,  -1},
        {1,  0},
        {0,  1},
        {-1, 0}
};

vector<vector<State>> ReadBoard(const string &path);

vector<State> ParseLine(const string &line);

void PrintBoard(const vector<vector<State>> &board);

const string CellString(const State &state);

vector<vector<State>> Search(vector<vector<State>> &board, const vector<int> &init, const vector<int> &goal);

int Heuristic(const int &x1, const int &y1, const int &x2, const int &y2);

void AddToOpen(vector<int> current, vector<vector<int>> &open, vector<vector<State>> &board);

void SortOpen(vector<vector<int>> *vector);

void ExpandNeighbours(const vector<int> &current, const vector<int> &goal, vector<vector<int>> &open,
                      vector<vector<State>> &board);

bool ValidateCell(const int &x, const int &y, const vector<vector<State>> &board);

int main() {
    vector<int> init{0, 0};
    vector<int> goal{2, 5};

    vector<vector<State>> board = ReadBoard("../1.board");
    vector<vector<State>> solution = Search(board, init, goal);
    PrintBoard(solution);
    return 0;
}

vector<vector<State>> Search(vector<vector<State>> &board, const vector<int> &init, const vector<int> &goal) {
    vector<vector<int >> open{};

    int x = init[0];
    int y = init[1];
    int g = 0;
    int h = Heuristic(x, y, goal[0], goal[1]);
    AddToOpen(vector<int>{x, y, g, h}, open, board);


    while (!open.empty()) {
        SortOpen(&open);
        vector<int> current = open.back();
        open.pop_back();

        int x2 = current[0];
        int y2 = current[1];
        board[x2][y2] = State::kPath;

        if (x2 == goal[0] && y2 == goal[1]) {
            board[init[0]][init[1]] = State::kStart;
            board[goal[0]][goal[1]] = State::kFinish;

            return board;
        }

        ExpandNeighbours(current, goal, open, board);
    }

    cout << "Could not find a path." << "\n";
    return vector<vector<State>>{};
}

void ExpandNeighbours(const vector<int> &current, const vector<int> &goal, vector<vector<int>> &open,
                      vector<vector<State>> &board) {

    int x = current[0];
    int y = current[1];
    int g = current[2];

    for (auto direction: directionDeltas) {
        int x2 = x + direction[0];
        int y2 = y + direction[1];


        if (ValidateCell(x2, y2, board)) {
            int g2 = g + 1;
            int h2 = Heuristic(x2, y2, goal[0], goal[1]);

            AddToOpen(vector<int>{x2, y2, g2, h2}, open, board);
        }
    }
}

bool ValidateCell(const int &x, const int &y, const vector<vector<State>> &board) {
    bool x_valid = x >= 0 && x < board.size();
    bool y_valid = y >= 0 && y < board[0].size();

    return x_valid && y_valid && board[x][y] == State::kEmpty;
}

bool Compare(const vector<int> &a, const vector<int> &b) {
    int f1 = a[2] + a[3];
    int f2 = b[2] + b[3];

    return f1 > f2;
}

void SortOpen(vector<vector<int>> *vector) {
    sort(vector->begin(), vector->end(), Compare);
}


void AddToOpen(vector<int> current, vector<vector<int>> &open, vector<vector<State>> &board) {
    board[current[0]][current[1]] = State::kClosed;
    open.push_back(current);
}

int Heuristic(const int &x1, const int &y1, const int &x2, const int &y2) {
    return abs(x2 - x1) + abs(y2 - y1);
}

vector<vector<State>> ReadBoard(const string &path) {
    vector<vector<State>> board{};

    ifstream file(path);
    if (file) {
        string line;
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            vector<State> row = ParseLine(line);
            board.push_back(row);
        }
    }

    return board;
}

vector<State> ParseLine(const string &line) {
    vector<State> row{};
    istringstream s_line(line);

    int n;
    char c;
    if (s_line) {
        while (s_line >> n >> c && c == ',') {
            if (n == 0) {
                row.push_back(State::kEmpty);
            } else {
                row.push_back(State::kObstacle);
            }
        }
    }

    return row;
}

void PrintBoard(const vector<vector<State>> &board) {
    for (const vector<State> &row : board) {
        for (const State &state: row) {
            cout << CellString(state);
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

const string CellString(const State &state) {
    switch (state) {
        case State::kEmpty:
            return "0   ";
        case State::kObstacle:
            return "1   ";
        case State::kClosed:
            return "x   ";
        case State::kPath:
            return "=   ";
        case State::kStart:
            return "S   ";
        case State::kFinish:
            return "F   ";
    }
}
```

Now it prints:

```
S   1   0   0   0   0   
=   1   x   x   x   0   
=   1   =   =   =   F   
=   1   =   =   x   0   
=   =   =   x   1   0
```

I would expect to print

```
S   1   0   0   0   0   
=   1   x   x   x   0   
=   1   =   =   =   F   
=   1   =   x   x   0   
=   =   =   x   1   0
```

The 1.board file looks like this:

```
0,1,0,0,0,0,
0,1,0,0,0,0,
0,1,0,0,0,0,
0,1,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,1,0,
```

Comment: It's *very* difficult to see the difference between "Now it prints:" and "I would expect to print". Took me ages to see it in the 4th row and 4th column.

Comment: Your solution is not recursive, which means there may be boards that your algorithm may deem unsolvable, even though they would be with recursion. If you are fine with it then I'm fine with it too :)

Comment: This solution is entirely missing the part of following the parent-pointers back from the goal to the start.

Comment: @Dialecticus A* is not recursive, that doesn't make it incomplete.

Comment: @harold you put into words what I actually wanted to say, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general remarks first, use structure with understandable names instead of `std::vector` of fixed size:

```cpp
struct OpenedNode
{
    Coordinate pos; // x, y
    int g; // Cost from start
    int h; // heuristic
};
```

`State::kPath` is not necessary path to goal, but visited nodes (and so you need to construct path once you reach goal).
`State::kClosed` is the opened nodes, so the next one to visit.

Then according to you heuristic:

```
S   X   5   4   3   2   
6   X   4   3   2   1   
5   X   3   2   1   0   
6   X   4   3   2   1   
7   6   5   4   X   2
```

and cost to start:

```
S   X   10  11  12  13   
1   X   9   10  11  12   
2   X   8   9   10   F   
3   X   7   8   9   10   
4   5   6   7   X   11
```

So total is:

```
 S  X   15  15  13  15   
 7  X   13  13  12  13   
 7  X   11  11  11   F   
 9  X   11  11  11  11   
11  11  11  11  X   13
```

One you are at `{5,2}`, you have 2 open nodes with equivalent cost (`g + h`).

It appears that you choose `{4, 2}` (as `{5, 3}` has not been visited), adding 2 new nodes which are also equivalent.

Then you have to take one from the 3 candidates (neither is better, as they have the same cost (`g + h`)) and so on until you go to destination.